# Get the Max value based on Criteria, then repeat once the criteria is met

Tags: excel

I have 4 columns A , B , C , D

I would like to get in column D the maximum miles from column B.

I would like the count to start from column A at First Line.
The count should stop at the next First Line then start counting the max again until the next instance of First Line shows up on column A.

[image]

Those are my expected results

[image]

I have tried this, but this returns the max from the whole column and i don't know how to make it recount once First Line is met.

```
=IF(I3="Multi-Drop",MAX(H:H),"")
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have another picture showing what the results should look like? I'm a bit confused as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there any significance to the blank rows in the table?

Comment: Also, please, post what you have tried. Also, replying this data is really annoying. Can you post a data to copy/paste or upload somewhere a file example? Help the community to help you

Comment: Edited, thank you
Also the blanks can be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to get the max per section, provided you add an additional `First Line` at the very end, so the function knows where to stop:

```
=MAX(INDEX(B$2:B2,MATCH("zzz",A$2:A2)):INDEX(B2:B$28,MATCH("First Line",A3:A$28,0)))
```

[image]

Ok, so this is not exactly what you have asked for, and to do that, the formula will have to become longer... The below removes some duplicates, but we still have duplicate 120 because that's the max:

```
=IF(MAX(INDEX(B$2:B2,MATCH("zzz",A$2:A2)):INDEX(B2:B$28,MATCH("First Line",A3:A$28,0)))=B2,MAX(INDEX(B$2:B2,MATCH("zzz",A$2:A2)):INDEX(B2:B$28,MATCH("First Line",A3:A$28,0))),"")
```

[image]

And the below removes the duplicates of the max as well:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(INDEX(B$2:B2,MATCH("zzz",A$2:A2)):B2,B2)=1,MAX(INDEX(B$2:B2,MATCH("zzz",A$2:A2)):INDEX(B2:B$28,MATCH("First Line",A3:A$28,0)))=B2),MAX(INDEX(B$2:B2,MATCH("zzz",A$2:A2)):INDEX(B2:B$28,MATCH("First Line",A3:A$28,0))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi,

I have tried this, it goes good in the beginning, problem is i have around 2000 lines on my spreadsheet. I have tried to upgrade it to my needs but it still loses the plot at some point.

https://imgur.com/0SU5Ea8

Comment: @GabiTopciu Look for A$28 and B$28 in the formula and change those to the cell below last row of your table. So if your table ends at A2000, use A$2001.

Comment: @GabiTopciu Can you tell me what is the formula at the point where it's failing? The snapshots are not helping me figure out what might be going wrong.